# "GIT_DIR=myproject.git git init" : What this command line doing on bash?

Tags: git, bash, shell, environment-variables

When initialize a new git repository (on Linux/Ubuntu), we use:

```
# What this doing:
GIT_DIR=myproject.git git init  
#The above line will output: Initialized empty Git Repo...

cd myproject.git  
git --bare update-server-info  
cp hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
```

The first line "**GIT_DIR=...**" confuses me, it seems bash will get a env variable and git use the first to init the new project, BUT how?  Who can explain this little magic?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"?  The shell grammar specifies that assignments are set in the environment of the command.  The shell parses the command line and when it sees an assignment, it makes that assignment in the environment before it starts the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of Bash and other Bourne-compatible shells:

```
VAR=val cmd
```

runs `cmd` with `VAR` set to `val` and otherwise the environment of the shell itself.

Try running the following commands:

```
printenv
export FOO=bar
printenv | grep '^FOO='
FOO=baz printenv | grep '^FOO='
```

Comment: This is nice AND enlightening answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Bourne-compatible shells, variables may be assigned without the `export` keyword.
If used in front of a program to run, the variables will be exported to the environment
and thus appear as real environment variables to the program:

```
$ VARIABLE=value ./myprogram [arguments]
```

On systems that have the env program, you can do it like this:

```
$ env VARIABLE=value ./myprogram [arguments]
```

Comment: Not sure you can say "Unix shells".  The csh family of shells probably would be considered in the class of "Unix shells", but they do not recognize this syntax.  (Whether or not csh is an abomination is a different topic altogether.)